# Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments in gradle 6.0.1

Tags: gradle

I am writing gradle script like this using gradle 6.0.1 in my root build.gradle in multiproject:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    }
}
```

when I compile using:

```
gradle clean build -x test
```

throw this error:

```
$ gradle clean build -x test --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/dolphin/source/dabai/microservice/build.gradle' line: 54

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'microservice'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'microservice'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:242)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
```

how to write to make it work.I want to write onece in my root build.gradle file,and all subproject could automatic added and no need to write again.ps:when I put the dependencies out of subprojects it works fine,but I have to add lombok plugin in every subproject build.gradle file.It is ugly.